Return a value depending on if record in related table matches parent table using arcade in field maps web designer
I would like to return the values, good or bad, depending on if a value of a field in the related table matches a value in a field in the parent table. The two values are pressure in PSI and I am using the field maps web designer.
Essentially, surveyors are entering an input PSI in the related table, and then I want a calculated field in the parent layer to grab the latest survey's input PSI and compare it to a field in the parent layer called Target PSI which already has a value in it. If the value in input PSI matches Target PSI return good, if they don't match return bad.
This is my code below:
  // load the related rows, using the name of the relationship class
var related_rows = FeaturesetByRelationshipName($feature, "GIS.SDE.tbl_Valve_FieldPressure")

// get the latest survey
var latest_survey = First(OrderBy(related_rows, "created_date DESC"))

// return a default value if no survey was found
if(latest_survey == null) {
    return "Not surveyed yet"
}

// return good or bad depending on PSI
if(latest_survey.InputPostValvePressure == latest_survey.TargetPSI) {
    return "Good"
}
return "Bad"

The code works in the web designer, but when I go in field maps to test it just says failed to calculate. Anyone have any idea?

Have you seen this thread?
